# Why does `rm writeprotectedfile <<< ""` delete the file?

Tags: bash, rm, here-string

The default behaviour of the GNU `rm` command when asked to delete write-protected files is to interactively ask whether the user wants to delete each of the files. This is quite inconvenient in many situations.

A crude general way to supply an interactive command invocation with *no meaningful input* is to use a here-string. I expected that in this case,

```bash
touch wpf && chmod -w wpf
rm wpf <<< ""
```

would result in the command being aborted, i.e. the file still being there afterwards, much like when I try `rm wpf` and just hit <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> upon the prompt.

To my surprise however, it actually results in the file being deleted. 
(Ubuntu 18.04, GNU Bash 4.4.20, coreutils 8.28)

What's going on here, and does it also have ramifications for similar situations?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, `echo "" | rm file` will also delete it. Looks like `rm ` detects whether its input is linked to a terminal or not.

Comment: according to **man rm** Otherwise, if a file is unwritable, standard input is a terminal, and the -f or --force option is not given, or the -i or --interactive=always option is given, rm prompts the user  for  whether to remove the file.

Comment: my understanding is that If one condition is not met, **rm** will silently delete

Comment: @Archemar sounds like an answer! I think you're right and that's where it's documented. In this case, standard input is not a terminal.

Comment: I'm still amazed by information found (sometime) in **man** :D

Comment: That's [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) behaviour, not specific to the GNU implementation of `rm`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is it, though? AFAICS, nothing there really specifies the behaviour in case standard input is _not_ a terminal.

Comment: If stdin is not a terminal, that just carries on to step 4.

Comment: I can not reproduce. The file is not erased.

Comment: @QuartzCristal interesting, what coreutils are you using?

Comment: Coreutils 8.32 @leftaroundabout